# how to remove value from the contact form of jetpack wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

Hi I am using jetpack plugin to generate my contact form. This is the code the plugin generates

```
[contact-form][contact-field label='Name' type='name' required='1'/]
[contact-field label='Phone' type='text' required='1'/]
[contact-field label='Email' type='email'/]
[contact-field label='Comment' type='textarea' required='1'/][/contact-form]
```

The problem is it generates a value attribute in the html form, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="21-name" id="21-name" value="Roberto Taramasco" class="name">
```

Is there a way to prefent jetpack from generating the `value` tag?
I tried to add `default=" "` but did not work, and also tried `value=" "` but it did not solve it

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you are logged in, it should be pulling your user account information. Could you try a different browser, just to make sure?

If a non-logged in user looks at the page, the fields are empty (which is the intended default if logged out).

Answer (score -1):

I confirm it is related to logged users, or info saved in chrome